# Load namespaces with composer as psr-0 libraries

Tags: namespaces, composer-php, silex, psr-0

I am using Silex (and so, composer) for any web application project.

I would like to autoload 4 entities and forms:

1. FSB\MyProject\Entity\Booking --> /src/FSB/MyProject/Entity/Booking.php
2. FSB\MyProject\Form\BookingType --> /src/FSB/MyProject/Form/BookingType.php
3. FSB\MyProject\Entity\Contact --> /src/FSB/MyProject/Entity/Contact.php
4. FSB\MyProject\Form\ContactType --> /src/FSB/MyProject/Form/ContactType.php

The composer.json is defined with a psr-0 array:

```
{
    "require": {
        "silex/silex": "~1.0",
        [...]
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-0": {
            "FSB": "src/"
        }
    }
}
```

Then in my index.php file I just call :

```
use FSB\MyProject\Entity\Contact;
use FSB\MyProject\Form\ContactType;
use FSB\MyProject\Entity\Booking;
use FSB\MyProject\Form\BookingType;

$contact = new Contact();
```

Everything works fine in my dev-environment, MAMP, php 5.4

But it breaks on my production server, Apache2 on Ubuntu with PHP 5.4 too

> "PHP Fatal error:  Class 'FSB\MyProject\Entity\Contact' not found
>   in /[...]/index.php"

I've tried many ways to load my entities like :

```
{
    "require": {
        "silex/silex": "~1.0",
        [...]
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-0": {
            "FSB/Palmeraie": "src/",
        }
    }
}
```

Or even:

```
{
    "require": {
        "silex/silex": "~1.0",
        [...]
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-0": {
            "FSB\\Palmeraie\\Entity": "src/",
            "FSB\\Palmeraie\\Form": "src/"
        }
    }
}
```

--> Several ways are working in my dev-environment ; none on my production environment...

Did I miss something ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check your file/directory names for correct capitalization, file names on OS X are case insensitive opposed to those on Linux/Unix file systems.

Comment: I was wondering about it in fact, how are these folders supposed to be written ?
Actually, I have a src/ folder in lowercases and the FSB/MyProject/Entity folders as written here.

Comment: You can write them any way you want although CamelCase is the convention. But the path of the file and the namespaces and class names have to match exactly.

Comment: And should I precise something for psr-0 ?

I mean "autoload": { "psr-0": { "FSB/MyProject": "src/" }} or is it better to let it blank ? ("autoload": { "psr-0": { "": "src/" }}

Comment: If you have just one base directory it is OK to use `""`.

Comment: Finally, it does not like my name I think, I just have updated it with another namespace and it works... But no way to make it works my the complete namespace Me\MyProject\Entity etc.

Anyway, it works for this time.

Answer (score 1):

Execute "composer update" and it will work again.